# Google Cloud Storage write issue

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to use App Engine to write to a Storage bucket, but I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR    2017-07-04 02:42:54,057 api_server.py:374] Exception while 
handling service_name: "app_identity_service"
method: "GetAccessToken"
request: "\n7https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control"
request_id: "AgsXRTFEbS"
```

and further down:

```
RuntimeError: TypeError("unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 
'NoneType'",)
```

I'm pretty faithfully following this:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage

I believe this is an auth issue; but I THINK that app engine should have all of the permissions.

Thanks

Comment: Without seeing the code and knowing which line is failing, it's hard to offer any useful advice here. Could you post the section of your code that's failing?

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you are trying to add an int to something that is coming up as `None`.  Perhaps a Post variable, or a query.  Check the line of code yielding that error.

Comment: FWIW, in general it's also a good idea to provide the full stack trace...

Comment: Thanks, it turned out to be an authorization issue. I needed to copy a credentials json file into my working directory and it worked.